# How to fix workbook with macros that aren't working anymore?

Tags: excel, vba

I know my way around Excel but I've never worked with Macros/VBA before.

I have a workbook where I input data for payment transactions which should convert to a .txt file (after pressing a button) with the data so that I can use it for batch payments.

When I press the button to convert to Excel, it throws the error "Cannot run the macro "***". The macros may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

I've tried enabling things through the Trust Centre.

I did a bit more digging and saw that there was no code. I wonder how this happened.

I found and watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yl7GKPXI9to) and was able to do the conversion.

Now my issues are:

- From the video, I need to specify a worksheet name and a range for where the data is. Is there a way to do this without having to change that individually for each sheet?
- If I save the sheet anywhere except the Downloads folder, it throws the error "Bad file name or number" (Error 52)
- I had a saved, working copy at 11:53. Now, when I click the button to do the conversion, it doesn't work as in the button doesn't respond at all. I go into design mode and see that the code is there but the button doesn't work.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

- I tried adding the other locations as Trusted Locations in the Trust Centre
- I ran the code straight from VBA instead of pressing the button

Comment: If the code is there but the button doesn't work it could be that the macro name has changed?  Right-click the button and select `Assign Macro`.  It will give you a list of macro names - select the one you need.  If there's no `Assign Macro` option there should be a `View Code` option instead - select that and enter the macro name between the `Private Sub <button name>` and `End Sub`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you for your suggestion. It doesn't even let me right-click the button. Interestingly, I just went into the Developer tab and pressed the button, now it's working fine.